# Where to write try statment?

Tags: swift, do-catch

What are the differences between writing try before variable or after it assignment sign? I mean this:

```swift
do {
    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundUrl!)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

and this:

```swift
do {
    try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundUrl!)
}
catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Both of them work I'm just curious.